# Xamarin profiler - iOS simulator remoted to PC - TimeOut

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, timeout, profiler

I downloaded a trial of `VS2015 Entreprise` to try `Xamarin Profiler`.
When I starts it (from VS) it launches the app on the `iOS` Simulator (remoted to the PC) but then stops due to some kind of time out. Here is the error line in the log:

> Error occured on run testiOS.app: didn't get a connection from the Mac agent after 30 seconds,
>   terminating

Does anyone encountered this issue? Maybe there is a way to increase the time above 30 secs?

Comment: I have the same problem, and also don't know how to fix it. It worked fine for android. Try apple profiler from xcode. Just open "Instruments" and select "Allocations".